# Ticker symbols supported by googlefinance function

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

The GOOGLEFINANCE function in Google Sheets allows you to lookup the price (or other attribute) of a stock or instrument.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

However, the documentation for which symbols it supports is sparse.

For example, [this fund](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-ftse-developed-world-ex-uk-equity-index-fund-accumulation-shares?intcmpgn=equityglobal_ftsedevelopedworldexukequityindexfund_fund_link) has a symbol "GB00B59G4Q73", and searching for this in [Yahoo finance works](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/0P0000KSP6.L?p=0P0000KSP6.L&.tsrc=fin-srch).

But neither this nor the symbol "0P0000KSP6.L" works in Google Sheets, giving the error "When evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'GB00B59G4Q73' returned no data."

How can I determine if I am using the correct symbol, or if the function does not support this symbol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is your "official documentation":

> ticker - The ticker symbol for the security to consider.
>
> - Note: Reuters Instrument Codes are no longer supported. For example, ticker 123.TO or XYZ.AX would not work. Instead, use TSE:123 or ASX:XYZ.
> - Recommended: Add an exchange to avoid discrepancies. For example, use “NASDAQ:GOOG” instead of “GOOG." If an exchange is not specified, GOOGLEFINANCE will use its best judgement to choose one for you.

meaning that the best you can do is to go to **https://www.google.com/finance** and search for your ticker there instead of yahoo or other suppliers that are not supported

---

but you can always scrape it from yahoo:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/0P0000KSP6.L?p=0P0000KSP6.L&.tsrc=fin-srch", "//*"), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col1 contains 'Vanguard FTSE Dev World ex UK Equity Index AccLSE - LSE' 
  limit 1 
  offset 8", 0), "GBp(.*)"), "-"), ",", )*1
```

[image]

Comment: where is the source of that quote from the "official documentation". Can you please link to it?

Comment: I searched for (and successfully found) currency pairs that are present on google.com/finance, but the ticker does *not* match the URL. How do you find out the authoritative name for the ticker after you've found it on google.com/finance ?

Comment: @MichaelAltfield https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If the ticker is on Google Finance but it doesn't show the price on Sheets, try fetching from Google Finance itself:

```
=IFNA(IFNA(GOOGLEFINANCE(A1&":"&B1, "price"), IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/"&B1&":"&A1&"","//div[@data-last-price]/@data-last-price")),0)
```

This uses:

- `IFNA` to catch any errors
- `GOOGLEFINANCE` with market (A1) and ticker (B1)
- `IMPORTXML` to get data from Google Finance's page with ticker (B1) and market (A1)
- `//div[@data-last-price]/@data-last-price` to find a DIV element with an attribute called "data-last-price" and then get that attribute.

It's not quite the same, but it helps.